# android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.PositionMetadata can not resolve

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview, navigationview

I am using ExpandableListView in Navigationview.
Suddenly i am getting below error.
So, There are no ExpandableListConnector class in android.Widget package.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ExpandableListConnector$PositionMetadata android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getUnflattenedPos(int)' on a null object reference

I thought that it is issue of invalidation and all.So, I tried Invalidate and restart, Clean Project, Build Project. Even i remove .idea and .iml file project and build whole project again.

I do not know why there is no class ExpandableListConnector in android.widget package. Because its default package and i cant modify it.

I am using

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

And

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

So, if any one know regard this issue please aware me.